# Method onChange just get the last array value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am starting to learn React and i have difficulty to save the name Installatins of my groups in a state that I receive in Json.

```
class EditionGroup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      installations: [],
      groups: [],
      nameInstallGroup: [],
    };
```

my `JSON`:

```
"Default": [
    {
      "IdGroup": "1",
      "NameGroup": "Group1",
      "Installations": [
        {
          "IdInstallation": "1",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 1"
        },
        {
          "IdInstallation": "2",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 2"
        },
        {
          "IdInstallation": "3",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 3"
        },
        {
          "IdInstallation": "4",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "IdGroup": "2",
      "NameGroup": "Group2",
      "Installations": [
        {
          "IdInstallation": "5",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 5"
        },
        {
          "IdInstallation": "6",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 6"
        },
        {
          "IdInstallation": "7",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 7"
        },
        {
          "IdInstallation": "8",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 8"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "IdGroup": "3",
      "NameGroup": "Group3",
      "Installations": [
        {
          "IdInstallation": "9",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 9"
        },
        {
          "IdInstallation": "10",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 10"
        },
        {
          "IdInstallation": "11",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 11"
        },
        {
          "IdInstallation": "12",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "IdGroup": "4",
      "NameGroup": "Group4",
      "Installations": [
        {
          "IdInstallation": "13",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 13"
        },
        {
          "IdInstallation": "14",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 14"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "IdGroup": "5",
      "NameGroup": "Group5",
      "Installations": [
        {
          "IdInstallation": "15",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 15"
        },
        {
          "IdInstallation": "16",
          "NameInstallation": "Installation 16"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My method

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value }, () => {
      return this.state.groups.map((groupOption, index) => {
        const { IdGroup, NameGroup, Installations } = groupOption; // destructor

        if (this.state.value === IdGroup) {
          console.log('true');
          groupOption.Installations.map((installFromGroup, index2) => {
            const { IdInstallation, NameInstallation } = installFromGroup; // destructor

            this.setState({ nameInstallGroup: [...this.state.nameInstallGroup, NameInstallation] });
            console.log(NameInstallation);
            console.log(this.state.nameInstallGroup);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Just give me the last install name of each group.

How can I save all installations in a state of a group that has been selected ?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let us see you state declarations

Comment: sorry, i forgot show this.
I will edit the question

Comment: What is the expected state after a value change? array of strings `['Installation 10', 'Installation 11'...]` inside `this.state.nameInstallGroup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is async, so my guess would be that mapping this line:

```js
this.setState({ nameInstallGroup: [...this.state.nameInstallGroup, NameInstallation] });
```

is the issue.

You are telling it to add `NameInstallation` to your state array by desctructuring the current state array and adding a new value, but because of the async nature of `setState` you can't guarantee that `...this.state.nameInstallGroup` will have the updated state array yet.

Try using the updater form of `setState` instead to ensure that you are working with the most recent copy of state:

```js
this.setState((prevState) => ({ 
  ...prevState, 
  nameInstallGroup: [...prevState.nameInstallGroup, NameInstallation] 
}));
```

Comment: Your answer helped me, but when change group, the previous group's installations are still

Comment: Can you post an example of the how you want the state to look after? I'm not quite sure what the desired output is.

Comment: it's not necessary, i solved this problem putting at the beginning of the method-> this.setState({ nameInstallGroup: [] });

Answer (score 1):

When you need to react to state changes it is recommended to use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle method instead of `this.setState` callback.

If i understood correctly you want to set `this.state.nameInstallGroup` to the strings inside the `Installations` array of your JSON.

```js
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ value: event.target.value })
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  const { value, groups } = this.state

  if (value === prevState.value) return

  const { Installations } = groups.find(group => value === group.IdGroup)

  this.setState({ 
    nameInstallGroup: Installations
      .map(({ NameInstallation }) => NameInstallation) 
  })
}
```